# PHP sqlsrv plugin doesn't appear to support SQL try/catch statements.

Tags: php, sql-server

## Background

I have a simple database driven Semaphore in a php based web application that uses sqlsrv extension for windows and mssql for linux/max.

## The Problem

The query I'm running looks like:

```
      BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO Semaphores VALUES (:name, :process_id)
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 'false' AS Result
      END CATCH
```

This query works perfectly in SQL Server management studio. It also works in mssql extension. But in sqlsrv the catch query is never executed (or at least the results are not available).

The code for that looks like:

```
  $results = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $built_query);
  /* Error handling here left out for brevity */
  $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($row === FALSE)
  {
    // The insert worked so no rows exist causing the fetch array to fail.
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    // The select executed. Don't actually care about the contents.
    // This means the insert failed.
    return false;
  }
```

`$row` is always FALSE (ERROR STATE). No matter what the query looks like. I can force either branch of the query by itself and it works as expected.

## The question.

Why does the `sqlsrv_fetch_array` not obtain the catch results?